# Regular expression lookhead lookbehind

Tags: .net, regex, devexpress, expression, regex-lookarounds

I need some help with a regular expression for .NET, I have an input field for a telephone number.

I use a regex to format the value (`050 33 11 00`) to this format:

```
+32(0)50/33.11.00
```

But when I insert following value `09 323 23 56` I want to get following result:

```
+32(0)9/323.23.56
```

I've been looking at *lookahead* but can't find a working solution.

I'm using the folowing regex: `(\x2B{1}3{1}2{1}\x28{1}\d{1}\x29{1}\d{2}\/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})` which works for the first value.

The regex is placed on a textbox as editMask, so i would like instant live sanitizing.

```
textEdit.Mask.EditMask = editMask;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following replacement:

```
\b0(\d{1,2})\s+(\d{2,3})\s+(\d{2})\s+(\d{2})\b
```

This regex will match full "words" starting with `0`, followed by 1 or 2 digits, then whitespace, 2 or 3 digits, whitespace, 2 digits and again whitespace and 2 digits.

Replace with `+32(0)$1/$2.$3.$4`

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb0(%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D)%5Cs%2B(%5Cd%7B2%2C3%7D)%5Cs%2B(%5Cd%7B2%7D)%5Cs%2B(%5Cd%7B2%7D)%5Cb&i=050%2033%2011%2000%0D%0A%2B32(0)50%2F33.11.00%0D%0A09%20323%2023%2056%0D%0A%2B32(0)9%2F323.23.56&r=%2B32(0)%241%2F%242.%243.%244).

Comment: This isn't the solution i'm looking for, i want to create a regular expression that can be used as a mask for a textbox.

Comment: In order to get appropriate and prompt help, please clarify what you want. Currently, my answer is perfectly fitting the textbox validation on `Leave` (or whatever it is called when an element loses focus) event. If you mean *live sanitizing*, that is something different. Please be specific and update your question. I suggest posting the code for better understanding.